# Random walk with increasing step size

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

A random walk in the plane with step size $f(n)$ is *cool* if there is some constant $C$ such that it returns within a distance $C$ of the origin infinitely many times with probability $1$.

At the $n$-th step it moves $f(n)$ in one of the directions $x,y,-x,-y$ with equal probability.

$f(n)=1$ is cool.
Is there a cool $f(n)$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n)=\infty$?

If $f(n)$ eventually dominates $n!$, then $f(n)$ is uncool; is there a sharpest upper bound on the growth rate for $f(n)$ to be cool?

Comment: Are you dealing with 1-dimensional random walks [you say "returns to the interval (-C,+C)"] or 2-dimensional random walks [you say "one of the directions x,y,-x,-y"]?

Comment: Here's a rough heuristic that might hold.  If $f(n)$ grows slowly, and there isn't any weird modular behavior (e.g. all even steps after a certain time), then at time $n$ the variance of each coordinate is about $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n f(i)^2$.  Making a bunch of unsubstantiated independence/smoothness assumptions, you might then expect to hit near $0$ with probability proportional to $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)^2}$ (if each coordinate spreads out over a range of size $m$, both numbers might be small with probability about $1/m^2$).  (continued next comment)

Comment: If you take $f(n)$ growing sufficiently slowly, then the expected number of returns near $0$ is infinite, and (again making a bunch of unsubtantiated independence assumptions), you could hope that $f(n)$ is cool.

Comment: Have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.14996
it is somewhat relevant....

Comment: @StasVolkov Answers on Math SE should be self-contained, and link-only answers are highly discouraged.  In addition, you appear to be one of the authors of the linked paper.  When / if you repost an answer which better adheres to the standards of this site, please note that when one links to their own work here, one is expected to disclose their affiliation with that work.